# How to delete scrollbar from react resource-time for FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I used resource time of react Full Calendar, my code is:

```
resource:  'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors&',
 events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?single-day&for-resource-timeline&start=2020-12-03T00%3A00%3A00Z&end=2020-12-04T00%3A00%3A00Z&timeZone=UTC'

 <FullCalendar className="mb-4" defaultView="resourceTimelineDay"  locale={this.state.locale}  
resourceAreaWidth="15%" resourceLabelText="Praticiens" displayEventEnd={true}  header={{ left: "prev,next today", center: "title", right: "resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth"}} plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin,
 timelinePlugin]} ref={this.calendarComponentRef} events={this.state.events} contentHeight={500} 
resources={this.state.resource} schedulerLicenseKey='CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives'/>
```

When I run it, I get :

[image]

When I use the bottom scroll, I get:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I used this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-standard-view-demo

But, I want to make minTime and maxTime without scroll, and I want the rows will be all aligned not to 11h like the example.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Change the size of the calendar so that it fits completely in the designated area.

Comment: The width of the calendar (and thus whether a horizontal scrollbar is needed for the timeline) is largely dependent on the width of the container in which the calendar sits and/or the width you designate for the calendar itself. Although of course, the number of slots makes a difference to the width, and so does the [aspectRatio](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/aspectRatio) setting.

Comment: "I want to make minTime and maxTime"...go for it then, what's the problem?